# The stats command isn't returning any results?

Tags: splunk

I have the following query:

```
search (...) AND ERROR
    | rex field=error "^.*(?<vcbn>Value cannot be null.)$"
    | stats count(vcbn) by error
```

but for whatever reason the `stats count(vcbn) by error` isn't generating any results.

Additionally, the `rex field=error "^.*(?<vcbn>Value cannot be null.)$"` isn't building a new field in the list on the left of the event search results.

The search itself returns `170 events`.

Splunk Version: `4.3.3`

Answer (score 0):

looks like rex command is not able to extract at search time.

Can you provide sample _raw log event or 'error' field from the log event?

Also refer,

http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.0.1/SearchReference/Rex

Answer (score 0):

So after a good bit of research, I found a solution. The first problem was I misunderstood the `field` parameter for the `rex` command. It's meant to tell the parser was field to **search through.** The next thing I had to do was make sure to use the line characters `^` and `$`. Finally, I had to add the trailing `.*` to the mix so that it would look through the entire `_raw` field.

```
rex "^.*(?<vcbn>Value cannot be null).*$"
    | stats count(vcbn)
```

**NOTE:** the `_raw` field is built in.